# String Array from excel column

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, worksheet

How can I get a string array from a excel column? 
Let's say the column is like this

```
String0
String1
String2
String3
String4
```

and I want my array to be like: array[0]="String0", array[1]="String1" etc.

This is the code I am currently using but it always returns "null":

```
public static String[] excelvalue(String columnWanted, int sheet_no, String path) {
        int i = 0;
        String[] column_content_array = new String[140];
        try {
            int instindicator = -1;
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            HSSFWorkbook filename = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            HSSFSheet sheet = filename.getSheetAt(sheet_no);
            Integer columnNo = null;
            Integer rowNo = null;
            List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
            Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
            for (Cell cell : firstRow) {
                if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(columnWanted)) {
                    columnNo = cell.getColumnIndex();
                    rowNo = cell.getRowIndex();
                }
            }
            if (columnNo != null) {
                for (Row row : sheet) {
                    Cell c = row.getCell(columnNo);
                    String cell_value = "" + c;
                    cell_value = cell_value.trim();
                    try {
                        if ((!cell_value.equals("")) && (!cell_value.equals("null")) && (!cell_value.equals(columnWanted))) {
                            column_content_array[i] = cell_value;
                            i++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
                return column_content_array;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return column_content_array;
        }
        return column_content_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing just last reference of row and column, store all of them in a list like:

```
List<Integer> columnNos = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> rowNos = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in your for loop, just add rows and columns into list like:

```
if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(columnWanted)) {
    columnNos.add(cell.getColumnIndex());
    rowNo.add(cell.getRowIndex());
}
```

And then you could iterate over rows and columns and continue with your business logic further.